# How to convert a column which is int ; to varchar in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

create table empdept

```
(deptid int , dept_name char (20) ,dept_off char (20) , dept_head int);
```

I want to convert `deptid` to varchar

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), deptid) FROM empdept;
```

I did try this but not working

Comment: `ALTER TABLE empdept MODIFY deptid VARCHAR(10);`

Comment: Please publish an example of not working and if an error publish in full